# Listbox selection from a filtered list (VBA)

Tags: vba, listbox

I'm new to VBA and would appreciate any guidance on a current problem. I'm trying to create a list box which is populated based on the user's previous selections. I have used the DoFilter based on two cells "A2" and "B2" to reduce the number of rows (which I want to populate ListBox1)

```
Sub DoFilter()

Dim rCrit1 As Range, rCrit2 As Range, rRng1 As Range, rRng2 As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set rCrit1 = Sheets("QuestionBank").Range("A2")
Set rCrit2 = Sheets("QuestionBank").Range("B2")

Set rRng1 = Sheets("QuestionBank").Range("A5:AA2300")
Set rRng2 = Sheets("QuestionBank").Range("A6:AA2300")

With rRng1
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=rCrit1.Value, Operator:=xlOr
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=rCrit2.Value

End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I would then like this filtered range to populate my listbox1. However, as it currently stands it populates it with all the data, rather than just the filtered data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim rngItems As Range
    Set rngItems = Sheets("QuestionBank").Range("ItemList") 'ItemList refers to a column of data which populates the ListBox    

Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle
Me.ListBox1.Value = ""
Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
Me.ListBox1.Value = ""


    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    Me.ListBox2.Clear

    With Me.ListBox1
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .ListFillRange = ""
        For Each myCell In rngItems.Cells
            If Trim(myCell) <> "" Then
                .AddItem myCell.Value
            End If
        Next myCell
    End With

    Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
    Me.ListBox2.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any support (explanations of what your answer means is greatly appreciated as I am still in the early stages of learning VBA)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it.... For those that need the answer, I put the below in to the end of the DoFilter:

```
 Range("D6").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Name = "ItemList"
```